# Perl - How to decode or replace &#39; from database to single quote for browser display

Tags: mysql, perl, decode

I have found lots of questions close to this but, nothing that helped me solve it. Prob due to my lack of expertise.

PHP has  `html_entity_decode` which could have helped but, Perl does not, I believe.

In my MySQL database I have `&#39; &#34;` following lengths in a description like: `12&#39; 6&#34;`

I would like it to display as 12' 6".

I have tried:

```
$string =~ s/:[&#39;]:/'/g;
$string =~ s/:[&#34;]:/"/g;
$string =~ s/&#39;/'/g;
$string =~ s/&#34;/"/g;
$string =~ s/\&#39;/'/g;
$string =~ s/\&#34;/"/g;
$string =~ s/\&#39;/\'/g;
$string =~ s/\&#34;/\"/g;
perl -pi -e 's:&#39;:':g' $_; #crashes.
perl -pi -e 's:&#34;:":g' $string #also crashes.
system -pi -e 's:&#39;:':g' $_; #crashes.
system -pi -e 's:&#34;:":g' $string #also crashes.
```

I am at a loss. Can someone help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at [HTML::Entities](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTML%3a%3aEntities):

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use HTML::Entities;

my $str = '12&#39; 6&#34;';
print decode_entities($str);
```

Comment: +1 ... Rule of thumb: If PHP has it, **Perl has a CPAN library that does it** too.

Comment: What is I do not know if the prefix will be 12 or 6?

Comment: @DulcimerDude. It doesnt matter. The entity is `&#numval;`. You can put whatever you want before.

Comment: EXCELLENT! Worked great! You rock.